# Fastest way to get a list of files from S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My s3 bucket has 900k files (containing about 600GB of data) and will keep growing.

I'm working on a Laravel project which is deployed on a Vapor environment (serverless from aws lambda and I have a 15min execution limit).
Using the default Laravel stuff  `Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('');` it instantly runs out of memory, so given my limits I think I should be using straight CLI commands and interpret those results.

In this situation, just doing a simple command like this is not enough.

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://tc-v3-live --recursive --summarize

[.......]
2020-11-13 17:14:14   4325  bla-bla-file.pdf

Total Objects: 969451
   Total Size: 575558891206
```

What I'm looking for is a way to get only the filenames without the timestamp or the filesize - assuming that would be way much faster. The example above takes 7 minutes to execute with the default maximum chunk size of 1000.

So idealy I'd like to use something like

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://tc-v3-live --no-timestamp --no-size
```

Comment: Is it something that you need to do once only, or once a day/week? Or maybe it must be done for any request?

Comment: Like @Marcin said, if it's periodical, then S3 inventory (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) is the best way. If you want to do this all the time and for buckets *that* large, then I'd say that's not a good design, because API limits object count per request for a reason and you can't really override that.

Comment: @Marcin - it would be a consistency test once a day: do I have all the files in my db in s3 as well?

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha thank you! didn't know about this, I'll have a look